# Compilation of pure LaTeX (or beamer) with Pandoc lasts for over 30 min

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

I am using WSL 2 (Ubuntu 20.04) and Windows Terminal setting to compile markdown file into the beamer presentation. Unfortunately if I am trying to use pandoc 2.5 to compile it, the time of compilation lasts over 30 min (doesn't matter if it is by pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX). During compilation large amounts of memory (over 7 Gb sometimes) and cpu are taken. I am now using full texlive installation, and if I compile minimal LaTeX file it takes about 7 s. on pdfLaTeX and 11 s. on XeLaTeX. I've tried to check if there is any difference between compilation on /mnt/c and in virtual partition, but I haven't seen any.

When I run `--verbose` it tends to stop for a long time there:

```
[makePDF] temp dir:
./tex2pdf.-e12d1f709f7253a6
[makePDF] Command line:
pdflatex "-halt-on-error" "-interaction" "nonstopmode" "-output-directory" "./tex2pdf.-e12d1f709f7253a6" "./tex2pdf.-e12d1f709f7253a6/input.tex"

[makePDF] Environment:
("TEXINPUTS","./tex2pdf.-e12d1f709f7253a6:")
("SHELL","/bin/bash")
("TBBROOT","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/tbb")
("PSTLROOT","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/pstl")
("LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT","1")
("WSL_DISTRO_NAME","Ubuntu")
("PKG_CONFIG_PATH","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl/bin/pkgconfig")
("WT_SESSION","a85cfba4-d3cd-4767-a4ea-eb71304ea2fa")
("I_MPI_ROOT","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi")
("HOMEBREW_PREFIX","/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew")
("FI_PROVIDER_PATH","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib/prov:/usr/lib64/libfabric")
("NAME","DESKTOP-D00B1T9")
("PWD","/mnt/c/Users/Acer/Desktop/Linux/Home/Notes/Studies/Seminars/Dirac_Physical_Interpretation_of_QM")
("LOGNAME","qsiek")
("MANPATH","/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:/opt/intel/man/common:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/man:/opt/intel/documentation_2020/en/debugger/gdb-ia/man/:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man::")
("CUDADIR","/usr/local/cuda")
("HOME","/mnt/c/Users/Acer/Desktop/Linux")
("LANG","C.UTF-8")
("WSL_INTEROP","/run/WSL/25516_interop")
("LS_COLORS","rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:")
("INFOPATH","/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:/opt/intel/documentation_2020/en/debugger/gdb-ia/info/")
("IPPROOT","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/ipp")
("LESSCLOSE","/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s")
("TERM","xterm-256color")
("LESSOPEN","| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s")
("USER","qsiek")
("LIBRARY_PATH","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/ipp/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8")
("HOMEBREW_CELLAR","/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar")
("DISPLAY","172.29.96.1:0")
("SHLVL","1")
("HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY","/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew")
("CLASSPATH","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/mpi.jar")
("LD_LIBRARY_PATH","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/lib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/release:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/intel64/lib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/ipp/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8:/opt/intel/debugger_2020/python/intel64/lib:/opt/intel/debugger_2020/libipt/intel64/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64")
("XDG_RUNTIME_DIR","/tmp/runtime-qsiek")
("MKLROOT","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl")
("WSLENV","WT_SESSION::WT_PROFILE_ID")
("GCC_COLORS","error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01")
("XDG_DATA_DIRS","/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop")
("NLSPATH","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/locale/%l_%t/%N:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/locale/%l_%t/%N:/opt/intel/debugger_2020/gdb/intel64/share/locale/%l_%t/%N")
("PATH","/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/bin/intel64:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/bin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/intel64/libfabric/bin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mpi/intel64/bin:/opt/intel/debugger_2020/gdb/intel64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin")
("INTEL_PYTHONHOME","/opt/intel/debugger_2020/python/intel64/")
("HOSTTYPE","x86_64")
("INTEL_LICENSE_FILE","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/licenses:/opt/intel/licenses:/mnt/c/Users/Acer/Desktop/Linux/intel/licenses")
("CPATH","/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/ipp/include:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/mkl/include:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/pstl/include:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/pstl/stdlib:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/tbb/include:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.304/linux/tbb/include")
("WT_PROFILE_ID","{2c4de342-38b7-51cf-b940-2309a097f518}")
("OLDPWD","/mnt/c/Users/Acer/Desktop/Linux/Home/Notes/Studies/Seminars")
("_","/usr/bin/pandoc")

[makePDF] Contents of ./tex2pdf.-e12d1f709f7253a6/input.tex:
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode=true}{hyperref} % options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provides euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

% set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother


\date{}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

The markdown file is just:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.
```

and I use this command for minimal example (this particular example goes for under 4 min but I think it shouldn't take so long, slightly bigger with YAML header can take over 30 min):

```
pandoc -t latex test.md -o test.pdf
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Given that the TeX run is fast, it rather seems to be a pandoc issue, better asked to [pandoc@github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will ask there too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is offtopic.

Comment: On my laptop with Linux and TeXLive 2020, your `pandoc` command finishes within a few seconds. Are your folders shared folders, remote folders or folders connected to Dropbox, Google Drive or similar? Make sure that all files (`test.md`, TeX distribution and pandoc) are located on the local drive, to exclude some possible sources of delay. Wat you describe looks like some timeout. Are all style files mentioned in the log file already installed on your computer? Maybe `pdflatex` invokes the package manager and the repository is not reachable.

Comment: I have synchronized another folder, but even disconnecting it doesn't change anything. I think those .sty files are on my drive because I checked few if they are available and they in fact were in texlive installation folder. There are no warnings either, it is just slow. I have just tried to export it to .tex and then run pdflatex, and it is still very slow - in stdout, lines such as this
```(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))``` persists for a few seconds. Every single one. And whole evaluation takes about 5.5 minutes.